# input type range output is not working for dynamic id's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, range

Input type range functionality is not working when the id values are dynamic how can i do that..?

```html
<input name="gdOverallscore" id="gdOverallscore" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" list="ticks" oninput="ageOutputId.value = gdOverallscore.value"/><output id="ageOutputId">0</output>

<h2>This is working fine in my case i have dynamic id which is loop"</h2>
<br>
<input  name="gdskill[<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>]"
       id="gdskill[<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>]" 
       type="range"
       min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" 
       list="ticks" 
       oninput="Output.value = gdskill[<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>].value"/>
<output id="Output">0</output>

<br>
<h2>
In the second one id values comes like this:
gdskill[1],gdskill[3],gdskill[4],gdskill[6] etc..

</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your Ouptut Id as well or else the output will become same for all hence it wont work..

```
<input name="[]" id="gdskill<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>"

 type="range" min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1"

oninput="Output<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>.value = gdskill<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>.value"/>

<output id="Output<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>">0</output>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using like this: Id like `gdOverallscore[0]` will not work.

```
 <?php

    $skillLabel['ssid']=10;

    ?>

    <input name="gdOverallscore" id="gdOverallscore" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" list="ticks" oninput="ageOutputId.value = gdOverallscore.value"/><output id="ageOutputId">0</output>


    <input  name="gdskill<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>"
           id="gdskill<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>" 
           type="range"
           min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" 
           list="ticks" 
           oninput="Output.value = gdskill<?php echo  $skillLabel['ssid'];?>.value"/>
    <output id="Output">0</output>
```

**In Case of MUltiple:**

```
<?php

$skillLabel['ssid'][0]=10;
$skillLabel['ssid'][1]=11;

?>

<?php foreach($skillLabel['ssid'] as $key=>$value){?>
<input  name="gdskill<?php echo  $value;?>"
       id="gdskill<?php echo  $value;?>" 
       type="range"
       min="0" value="0" max="10" step="1" 
       list="ticks" 
       oninput="Output<?php echo  $value;?>.value = gdskill<?php echo  $value;?>.value"/>
<output id="Output<?php echo  $value;?>">0</output>

<?php }?>
```

[DEMO](http://main.xfiddle.com/60abc423/test.php)

Comment: Not working.. the problem is near `<` it means `<?php`

Comment: @AbidAli i tested with `<?php  $skillLabel['ssid']=10;?>` and it is working fine.

Comment: @AbidAli see the demo.

Comment: can you give the snippet, i changed only id. because i have ither functionality with name.

Comment: @AbidAli the above is the code there also. Name is useful for php so you can still use `name` in `array format` but not `id`. Just copy paste the entire code and see.